# SLURM loading modules vs using library from virtual environment

Tags: pytorch, cluster-computing, slurm

I'm relatively new to using clusters, in our uni we have one that is operated using slurm.
I'm trying to train a model that I can run locally on my CPU with my virtual enviroment

However when I try using the following script:

```
`#!/bin/csh

#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:1
#SBATCH --time=4:0:0
#SBATCH --<mymail>


source <VENV_PATH>/bin/activate.csh
python3 --version
which python3
set RUNPATH="my_path"
cd $RUNPATH

python3 my_prog.py
```

I get the following error: `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torchvision"`
and I find this to be funny because when I run my program locally with the same virtual environment it can obviously find the module.
Granted the cluster does have its own modules and I can load them using `module avail` I can see what modules are available, however I'm not sure they have the versions of cuda / pytorch that I need which is why, if possible, I would rather load them from the virtual environment.

Is such as thing possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?

Comment: `#!/bin/csh'
    #SBATCH COMMAND1

    module purge
    source /path/to/venv/bin/activate.csh

    `python3 prog.py <arguments>

    I believe the purge was the important part that I was missing